# Download base encoded file from spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to download an base64 encoded file on controller. Here is the code I have followed from few google stores.

```
 byte[] dataBytes = "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".getBytes();
                Utilities.downloadFile(response, "application/pdf",
                        "Filename.pdf", dataBytes);

    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName +"."+ fileType);
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedDocument.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    FileCopyUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
```

This is working fine and returning success on ajax but not showing download popup or not downloading as file on browser. Any help is appreciated.

Adding Js function.

```
 /**
 * DownloadFile
 * When clicked on download file, execute this.
 */
downloadFile: function(patientId, attachmentId ) {
    window.location.href = '/patient/details/attachments/download/' + patientId + '/' + attachmentId;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem is likely in the way you invoke this "download". Show that code. Standard things like `$.post` in jQuery cannot download files to the user's computer. You can refer to this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970672/2788

Comment: Editted question with the js function.

Comment: meybe you may use this jquey plugin https://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

Comment: @GowthamiReddy so no, that won't work. Standard jQuery `$.ajax` call won't initiate a download, you need to use a solution. Why not just generate a normal link, especially if it's a GET request.

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file started downloading with out getting corrupted after sending the bytes of encodedDocument instead of String.

```
/* Set the file properties*/
if(fileType == null) {
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
} else {
    response.setContentType(fileType);
}
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

/* Convert bytes to stream of objects*/
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedDocument);

/*Download copying the content to destination file*/
IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
response.flushBuffer();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not initiate download by ajax request! 
[Here you can find detail answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax).

**But the provided plugin is too much browser dependent**

As you expect to download via browser, so you need to make simple GET request by URL like `<a href="'/patient/details/attachments/download/{patientId}/{attachmentId}">Download</a>`

Comment: Yes i have done this but downloaded file is corrupted if it of type pdf.